# /<int:id> doesn't redirect to html in django

Tags: python, html, django

So I have a image in html redirect to a certain url:

```
<div class="image">
                    <a href="/accounts/startlistening/{{i.song_id}}">
                    <img src="{{i.image.url}}">
                </a>
                </div>
```

Here i.song_id gives a integer value.

The url.py is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('register/', views.registration, name="signup"),
    url('login/', views.loginUser, name="login"),
    url('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
    url('upload/', views.upload, name="upload"),
    url('startlistening/', views.startlistening, name="startlistening"),
    url('startlistening/<int:id>', views.player, name="player") 
]
```

The views.py for my player is:

```
def player(request, id):
    song = Song.objects.filter(song_id = id).first()
    return render(request, 'accounts/player.html',{'song':song})
```

But for some reasons on runserver, on clicking the image, it changes the url but doesn't redirect to player.html
Eg: on clicking it changed from http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/startlistening/ to http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/startlistening/17 but the content is same.

Edit: Worked after i changed all my url into path in urls.py

Comment: What does this have to do with `css` ? :) please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Where are you getting the `id` variable from?

Comment: Check if this {{i.song_id}} is printing your id. And send your Song model here

Comment: The models for song_id is
    ``song_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)``
    
@Dosbodoke

Comment: @RajaramKarki, Django Models do the work of putting an id automatcally, "song_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)" this is not good.

Comment: url('startlistening/<int:id>/', views.player, name="player") ||| Try to put this / after <int:id>

Comment: Use this ```url('startlistening/<int:id>/', views.player, name="player") ```

Comment: Same outcome even after / at the end @Ram

Comment: You could use this ```<a href="{% url 'startlistening' i.song_id %}"``` instead of what you have already used. What you've tried is like hardcoding.

Comment: Ya already tried that, I get NoReverseMatch error @Ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the old [`url` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#url) (Deprecated since Django 3.1, should be using `re_path` instead if regex is needed) instead of the [`path` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#path). Hence what is happening here is your pattern `startlistening/` matches the string `startlistening/17`, you can see this by trying the below snippet:

```
print(re.search(r'startlistening/', 'startlistening/17')) # returns a match
```

Furthermore `<int:id>` will not make a capturing group when you use the `url` / `re_path` function, hence that pattern is also incorrect.

All your patterns are designed as if you were using the `path` function hence you should change to using it:

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.registration, name="signup"),
    path('login/', views.loginUser, name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
    path('upload/', views.upload, name="upload"),
    path('startlistening/', views.startlistening, name="startlistening"),
    path('startlistening/<int:id>/', views.player, name="player") 
]
```

Next in your template simply write:

```
<a href="{% url 'player' i.song_id %}">
```

If you *want* to use `url` (you might have an older version of Django (Please upgrade if you do), **NOT recommended** otherwise) you can rewrite your patterns like so:

```
# You might also want to add a "^" to the start of the patterns, or if these patterns are included  somewhere add it to the start of the root pattern.
urlpatterns = [
    url('register/$', views.registration, name="signup"),
    url('login/$', views.loginUser, name="login"),
    url('logout/$', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
    url('upload/$', views.upload, name="upload"),
    url('startlistening/$', views.startlistening, name="startlistening"),
    url('startlistening/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.player, name="player") 
]
```

Comment: Tt worked!! Finally thanks a lot. I changed all url into path and in template i wrote `<a href="/accounts/startlistening/{{i.song_id}}"><button>Listen Song</button></a>` , it worked on image too, but i added a button. Its working fine now, thanks a looot dude.

Answer (score 0):

Change the url sequence to

```
path('startlistening/<int:id>', views.player, name="player"),
path('startlistening/', views.startlistening, name="startlistening")
```

Or even more explicit something like:

```
path('player/<int:id>', views.player, name="player"),
path('startlistening/', views.startlistening, name="startlistening")
```

Comment: Same outcome :(
on adding `url('player/<int:id>', views.player, name="player"),` it redirects to the homepage.

Comment: Did you also change your href to .../player/...?

Comment: Yes i did @Razenstein

Comment: See reply above ... I did not realize the add. mistake in url/path  .. see updated answer